# Does adding enumerators into Java enum break ABI?

Tags: java, jvm, abi, jls, jvm-bytecode

For example, in my code there is

```
public enum Color { RED, BLACK }
```

and I add a color later, that is

```
public enum Color { RED, BLACK, BLUE }
```

will this break ABI? That is, does my user need to recompile his Java classes?

Comment: Idea from [*Does adding enumerators into enum break ABI?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300561/does-adding-enumerators-into-enum-break-abi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. According to [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.26):

> #### 13.4.26. Evolution of Enums
>
> Adding or reordering constants in an enum will not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries.

Note that even reordering keeps compatibility, unlike in C/C++/C#.